# Remove minimum rank rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below.

```
Customer    Order        Rank
1             12           3
1             14           7
2             15           6
2             16           4
2             17           2
2             21           1
3             24           5
3             25           6
3             27           7
```

Now, I want to select all rows except for rows with minimum ranks for each customer. It should look like below.

```
Customer    Order        Rank
1             14           7
2             15           6
2             16           4
2             17           2
3             25           6
3             27           7
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `CTE` + `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Customer, [Order], Rank,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY Rank)
    FROM dbo.Customers
)
SELECT Customer, [Order], Rank 
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN > 1
ORDER BY Customer, Rank DESC
```

**Demo**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/444be/3/0

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT Customer,Order,Rank,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY Rank ) as rn FROM t
)
SELECT Customer,Order,Rank FROM CTE
WHERE rn >1
```